# add http_proxy to sidecar istio container

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I enabled istio injection in my namespace
I'm having trouble to reach an ip:port adress which I already added in my service entry

I have to set http_proxy env variable to be able to reach that website.

Is there a way to inject env variable in the sidecar container?

Comment: the solution is to add the proxy as a service entry

Comment: If this solved your issue, can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as answer for the greater visibility of community